# Next js - not able to override the styles from component library using scss

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, next.js

This post is originated from [the post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75fIq.png)

I'm using `react-simple-keyboard` and I try to override below style(class:react-simple-keyboard) from this library
[image]

by using scss

keyboard.module.scss

```
.react-simple-keyboard{
  width: 50% !important;
}
```

components/keyboard/index.js

```
import keyboardStyle from "./keyboard.module.scss";
...
// Do something using keyboardStyle
```

but not working

From the comments I've got from the post, I even try

```
:global(.react-simple-keyboard) {
  width: 50% !important;
}
```

but not working.

It throws error

```
 Selector ":global(.react-simple-keyboard)" is not pure (pure selectors must contain at least one local class or id)
```

**Update 1**

I try to add the class to `global.css` and it works, just wondering if I can do it in `keyboard.module.scss`

_app.tsx

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
...
```

Comment: Can you see in dev tools that it gets applied but is ignored?

Comment: @Damian Busz not applied. I can't see `.react-simple-keyboard` in dev tools

Comment: @Damian Busz check my update 1

Comment: cool, I was just working on codesandbox version with next.js! 
But I assume that just have to do this globally as it renders keyboard somewhere else in the DOM